# Trouble getting free API key in alpha vantage

Tags: alpha-vantage

It says **success redundant** when asking for the free API key after entering the basic info such as the organisation, what best describe you and email.

I am not getting the free API. What am I doing wrong?
I'm working on stock filtering project and stuck. Anyone help is highly appreciated.